# Where to ask about programming language recommendations?

Tags: discussion, support, site-recommendation

I'm looking to ask a question about recommendations for a language and/or framework which I can use to write a cross-platform program requiring OpenGL support. Where exactly should I ask this?

I tried 'Software Recommendations', but it got down-voted by at least one person, presumably as it's not really a question about software. I can't ask it in Stack Overflow, due to the strict 'no opinions' question policy there.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Recommendation questions are off-topic across all sites in the SE network. Best you can get is [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) but they don't do programming languages and they have high quality standards, check their help.

Comment: @rene - Clearly not entirely correct, or the Software Recommendations stack wouldn't exist.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin true, still no use for this OP.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177316/should-programming-language-recommendation-questions-be-closed-as-off-topic

Comment: There really isn't any place you can ask that as an official question.  But you should get useful feedback in chat.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an active participant there, but I think that your question is related to [Software Engineering SE](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/).

I suggest you to make your question very specific in order to avoid primarily-opinion based answers. For that ask for answers supported on facts or very specific experiences, also include your major goals, concerns and problems that you faced with frameworks that you already know.

Related questions

On Software Engineering

[When does a question fall into "allowable recommendation" category (good subjective) and when does it not?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3213/233431)

On Stack Overflow

[What exactly is a recommendation question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254393/1595451)